# How to Solve System.FormatException??

Tags: c#, sockets, formatexception

Tell me how to fix this Exception please, when the transfer occurs between the PC.

**Exception Thrown :**

> (System.FormatException)
>
> A System.FormatException was thrown: "Input string had an incorrect format."

In Line :

```
fileSize = Convert.ToInt32(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteFileSize));
```

### My whole Code :

---

```
private void Server()
{
    FileStream fs = null;
    BinaryWriter bw = null;
    int fileSize = 0;
    int bytesReceived = 0;
    int bufferInt = Int32.Parse(textBoxBYTE2.Text);

    byte[] bufferByte = new byte[bufferInt];
    byte[] byteFileName = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("empty");
    byte[] byteFileSize = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("empty");

    string fileName = "";

    int bytesTmp = 0;

    try
    {   
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ServerIP), int.Parse(textBoxPORT1.Text));
        Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );
        socket.Bind(localEndPoint);
        socket.Listen(10);
        Socket listener = socket.Accept();
        //[1] Принимаем имя
        bytesTmp = listener.Receive(byteFileName);
        fileName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteFileName, 0, bytesTmp);
        //[2] Принимаем размер
        listener.Receive(byteFileSize);

        fileSize = Convert.ToInt32(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteFileSize)); //Exception Thrown Here

        fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(textBoxPATH.Text, fileName), FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
        bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
        //<!--
        while (bytesReceived < fileSize)
        {
            if ((fileSize - bytesReceived) < bufferInt)
            {
                int bytes = (fileSize - bytesReceived);
                byte[] buf = new byte[bytes];
                bytes = listener.Receive(buf);
                bw.Write(buf, 0, bytes);
                bytesReceived = bytesReceived + bytes;
            } else {
                int bytes = listener.Receive(bufferByte);
                bw.Write(bufferByte, 0, bytes);
                bytesReceived = bytesReceived + bytes;
            }
        }
        //-->
        //Закрытие
        bw.Close();
        socket.Close();
        listener.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("" + e, "Сервер сообщает");
    }
}
private void Client()
{
    FileStream fs = null;
    BinaryReader br = null;
    int bytesSent = 0;
    int fileSize = 0;            
    int bufferInt = Int32.Parse(textBoxBYTE2.Text);
    byte[] bufferByte = new byte[bufferInt];
    byte[] byteFileName = new byte[512];
    byte[] byteFileSize = new byte[512];
    string fileName = "";

    try
    {
        Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        sender.Connect(textBoxADDRESS2.Text, int.Parse(textBoxPORT2.Text));
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(textBoxFILE.Text);
        fileName = fileInfo.Name;
        byteFileName = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileName);
        //[1] Передаем имя
        sender.Send(byteFileName);
        fs = new FileStream(textBoxFILE.Text, FileMode.Open);
        br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        fileSize = (int) fs.Length;
        byteFileSize = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.ToString(fileSize));
        //[2] Передаем размер файла
        sender.Send(byteFileSize);
        //<!--
        while (bytesSent < fileSize)
        {
            if ((fileSize - bytesSent) < bufferInt)
            {
                int bytes = (fileSize - bytesSent);
                byte[] buf = new byte[bytes];
                br.Read(buf, 0, bytes);
                sender.Send(buf);
                bytesSent = bytesSent + bytes;
            } else {
               br.Read(bufferByte, 0, bufferInt);
               sender.Send(bufferByte);
               bytesSent = bytesSent + bufferInt;
            } 
        }
        //-->
        //Закрытие
        br.Close();
        sender.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("" + e, "Клиент сообщает");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In your call to [`Socket.Receive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receive.aspx), you're ignoring how many bytes are *actually* read.

That raises two problems:

- How do you know when you've read enough?
- You're currently assuming that *all* of the byte array contains useful data, whereas some of it may well be the "old" data.

Comment: how best to proceed please advise, I have little experience in this area

Comment: @kmsboy: We'd need more detail on your protocol to start with. Is there any reason you're not just using HTTP, for example?

Comment: the task of learning, transfer a file over a socket with the specified buffer size

Comment: @kmsboy: So first work out *exactly* what your protocol looks like (byte for byte), then document it, then implement it - always bearing in mind that TCP/IP is a stream-based protocol.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you should be calling

```
fileSize = byteFileSize.Length;
```

Since `byteFileSize` is a `byte[]`

Comment: If `byteFileSize` is a `byte[]` then `Length` is already an `Int32`.

Comment: `byteFileSize.Length` is the length of the array (how many bytes it contains), not file size !!!