# Convert text to integer to compare in C#

Tags: c#, textbox, type-conversion, integer

The C# program receives a string labeled:

```
1.2345 V
```

I need to compare this value using < or > in a 'if' statement.
How do I convert the string above to a integer?
I tried to use:

```
int anInteger;
anInteger = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
anInteger = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
```

But it throws the error `System.FormatException: incorrect format`.

Comment: It's _not_ an integer but a double/decimal value. You also have to remvoe the `V` before you can parse it

Comment: what integer value do you expect out of `1.2345 V`?

Comment: Do you only want the numbers or does the `V` have a special meaning because that string cannot be converted to a numeric value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert string to integer in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344411/how-to-convert-string-to-integer-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Solve System.FormatException??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702431/how-to-solve-system-formatexception)

Answer (score 1):

In case you insist on *integer* (*dot* in `1.2345` shoud be *ignored* and final result is `12345`):

```
  // Any digits (including, say, Persian ones) are OK  
  int anInteger = (textBox1.Text
    .Where(c => char.IsDigit(c))
    .Aggregate(0, (s, a) => s * 10 + (int)char.GetNumericValue(a));
```

Or

```
  // Only '0'..'9' digits supported
  int anInteger = (textBox1.Text
    .Where(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9')
    .Aggregate(0, (s, a) => s * 10 + a - '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `V` at the end and use `decimal.Parse`/ `TryParse`:

```
decimal d;
bool validFormat = decimal.TryParse(textBox1.Text.TrimEnd('V', ' '), out d);
```

In my country which uses `,` as decimal and `.` as group separator this yields `12345`.

If you instead want to ignore anything that is not a digit in a string:

```
int number = int.Parse(new string(textBox1.Text.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray()));
```

Comment: In C#7 you can do `out decimal d`, to save a bit of space :)

Comment: and you might have to use invariant culture depending on questioners location

Comment: @YairHalberstadt: well, it works for me and i'm not using `.` as decimal separator. The result is `12345` which is a bit odd

Comment: In some countries it doesn't work, and the programmer spends hours trying to work out why .@Tim

Comment: @YairHalberstadt: the opposite is true, it seems OP also expects an integer and not a double, so it wouldn't work if he uses `InvariantCulture` which uses `.` as decimal separator

Comment: @TimSchmelter I just assumed that was a mistake

Comment: @YairHalberstadt: modified my answer to mention it

Answer (score 0):

Please also notice that depends on your current culture settings you can get different results.

Following code was run with de-DE culture settings

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");

string str = "1.23";
decimal val = decimal.Parse(str);
val.Dump(); // output 123

string str2 = "1,23";
decimal val2 = decimal.Parse(str2);
val2.Dump(); // output 1,23
```

Following code was run with en-US culture settings

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");

string str = "1.23";
decimal val = decimal.Parse(str);
val.Dump(); // output 1.23

string str2 = "1,23";
decimal val2 = decimal.Parse(str2);
val2.Dump(); // output 123
```

Please use LINQPad to run that code.

Answer (score 0):

you can try -

```
 decimal dec=2;
 string str = "3.23456";
 dec = Convert.ToDecimal(str.ToString());
 int a = Convert.ToInt32(dec);
```